# Need help regarding printf() in c

Tags: c, printf

Predict the output of the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf(" \"TEST %% C %% PROGRAM\"");
return 0;
}
```

Answer is "TEST % C % PROGRAM"

Why? I understand %% means it will print % ,but what about "\"\" thing in printf?

Comment: @Murphy I partly agree, but apparently the question is about an assignment which demands _inspection_ of the code and prohobits _execution_ of the code.

Comment: Basically there are some special characters, which needs to be escaped to be printed, backslash is one of them, it is nothing more difficult in that

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a string delimiter to define a start and an end to a string like

```
"Taha Paksu was here"
```

but what if you needed to use a quote inside the string? Like:

```
""Taha Paksu" was here" (you can see that the code highlighter is confused too)
```

Then the compiler would've been confused wherever the string starts and ends.

To prevent that, there exists **escape sequences**. To write a quote inside a quote delimited string, you need to escape it first. Like

```
"\"Taha Paksu\" was here"
```

The `\` character is used to describe a escape sequence like:

```
Escape sequence Hex value in ASCII  Character represented
\a  07  Alert (Beep, Bell) (added in C89)[1]
\b  08  Backspace
\f  0C  Formfeed
\n  0A  Newline (Line Feed); see notes below
\r  0D  Carriage Return
\t  09  Horizontal Tab
\v  0B  Vertical Tab
\\  5C  Backslash
\'  27  Single quotation mark
\"  22  Double quotation mark
\?  3F  Question mark (used to avoid trigraphs)
\nnn       note 1 any The byte whose numerical value is given by nnn interpreted as an octal number
\xhh…      any  The byte whose numerical value is given by hh… interpreted as a hexadecimal number
\e         note 2 1B    escape character (some character sets)
\Uhhhhhhhh note 3 none  Unicode code point where h is a hexadecimal digit
\uhhhh     note 4 none  Unicode code point below 10000 hexadecimal
```

if you want to output `\` in a string; you also need to escape it with `\\`

Table taken from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Answer (score 3):

`%` is the format specifier for `printf` and family specifically. So if you want to print out an actual percentage sign instead of using the format options of `printf` you have to escape it by using 2 instead of 1 : `%%`.

`\` is the global escape character for string literals.

This is needed because of certain characters, if we want to print out `John said : "Hello"` then we can't just use `printf("John said "Hello"");` since this will mess up the string literal (where does it end? the second `"`? the third??).

For this reason we need a character that signals that the next character should be interpreted literally and not programatically. 
To print out `John said : "Hello"` we would need : `printf("John said : \"Hello\"");`